# Show that A=$\{(x_1,...x_n) \in \Bbb R | -1\le x_1\le x_2\le ...x_n\le 1\} \subset \Bbb R^n $ is closed.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

The full question was:

Show that A=$\{(x_1,...x_n) \in \Bbb R \mid -1\le x_1\le x_2\le ...x_n\le 1\} \subset \Bbb R^n       $ is **compact**, but I was able to show correctly that it is bounded.

However my proof of it being closed didn't hold up.
I tried to show $ A^c  $ open.
So for some $x\in A^c, y\in A$, either

1. $x_{i+k}<x_i     $ for some $i$, and k is a positive integer.

   - $\Rightarrow d(x,y)\ge \frac1{\sqrt2} |x_{i+k} - x_i|\ge0\Rightarrow B(x,\frac12 |x_{i+k} - x_i|) \subset A^c  $
2. or $\exists\ x_i \notin\ [-1, 1] $

   - $\Rightarrow d(x,y)\ge |x_i - y_i|\gt 0 \Rightarrow B(x, \left(\frac{|x_i - y_i|}2\right) )\subset A^c$

Any suggestions? The corrector said 'You have only put an open interval around one co-ordinate, you need to do it for all of them' but i don't understand what he meant.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The corrector is wrong. Any product of open sets in a finite product is open, so if some coordinate is $x_i>1$ just multiply a small interval around that coordinate, by $\mathbb{R}$ on all the other coordinates.

Comment: @rewritten I think that's what I meant when answering the question, maybe I should have stated it explicitly. But what I have said does actually imply that $A^c$ is open?

Comment: What you say actually implies that $A^c$ is open. The corrector is probably expecting a solution like in ArthurFischer's response, but you are doing in a different way, you are pointing out actual balls, cenetered in an arbitrary points of $A^c$, which are contained in $A^c$ themselves (the balls). Arthur's response is more elegant, and simpler, but yours is anyway completely correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your corrector was partially incorrect.  The point is that if some $\mathbf{x} = \langle x_1 , \ldots , x_n \rangle$ does not belong to $A$, this is witnessed by a failure of the condition for at most two coordinates of $\mathbf{x}$.  We can then choose open intervals for these coordinates such that *regardless* of how we pick points to "pass through" these intervals, we get the same failure of being an element of $A$.  This would be the same as taking the projections onto these other coordinates to be the full $\mathbb{R}$.

Let's work through this question a bit more fully. If $\mathbf{x}$ is not in $A$, there are three possibilities.

1. If $x_1 < -1$, then consider the set $U = ( - \infty , -1 ) \times \mathbb{R} \times \cdots \mathbb{R}$.  This is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$, contains $\mathbf{x}$, and is disjoint from $A$ (since for any $\mathbf{y} = \langle y_1 , \ldots , y_n \rangle \in U$ we must have $y_1 < -1$
2. If $x_n > 1$, then consider $U = \mathbb{R} \times \cdots \times \mathbb{R} \times ( 1 , + \infty )$.  again this is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$, contains $\mathbf{x}$, and is disjoint from $A$ (since for any $\mathbf{y} = \langle y_1 , \ldots , y_n \rangle \in U$ we must have $y_n > 1$).
3. If $i < n$ is such that $x_i > x_{i+1}$, then let $a = \frac{x_i + x_{i+1}}2$, and consider the set $U = \mathbb{R} \times \cdots \times \mathbb{R} \times ( a , + \infty ) \times ( -\infty , a ) \times \mathbb{R} \times \cdots \mathbb{R}$ (where the "$(a,+\infty)$" appears on the $i^\text{th}$ coordinate).  This is open, contains $\mathbf{x}$, and is disjoint from $A$ (since for any $\mathbf{y} = \langle y_1 , \ldots , y_n \rangle \in U$ we must have $y_i > a > y_{i+1}$).

As you can see, in this third case we needed to consider open intervals for *two* coordinates.

Comment: So rather than defining $A^c$ you're showing if $x \in A^c$ it is contained in one of three of these open sets. And that's sufficient to imply that $A^c$ is open?

Comment: And also, is there any significance of choosing a as the midpoint between $ x_i, x_{i+1}$, or are you just choosing any point between them (which is possible because they're not equal)? And thanks so much for this answer!

Comment: @user113867: To show that a set $A$ is open, it suffices to find for each $x \in A$ an open set $U_x$ with $x \in U_x \subseteq A$.  (Then $A$ is the union of all these open sets $U_x$, and is thus open.)  For for the second comment, it was not important that I took the midpoint.  As you suggest, I just needed to take _some_ point strictly between, and the midpoint is the easiest to describe.

Answer (score 1):

---

Edit: I misread the problem, my apologies. Here's an edited answer

If $\xi_k=(x^1_k,...,x^n_k) \in A$ for all $k$ and $\xi_k$ converges to $\xi=(x^1,...,x^n),$ then $x^i_k$ converges to $x^i$ for every $1 \leq i \leq n.$

For each $k$, $x^i_k \leq x^{i+1}_k$ for each $i$ implies that $\lim_{k \to \infty}x^i_k \leq \lim_{k \to \infty}x^{i+1}_k.$ In particular, this implies that
$$-1 \leq x^1 \leq \cdots \leq x^n \leq 1,$$ which exactly means that $\xi \in A.$